# Android: share CSV file

Tags: android, csv, share

My aplication can generate CSV files that I want to share. I'm using MIME type `text/comma_separated_values/csv`, but when I send the `Intent` the chooser isn't shown, I guess my device doesn't know how to handle the file. Which type should I use?

This is my code:

```
    Uri csv = lh.createDailyCSV();

    if(csv == null){
         Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_creating_csv), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/comma_separated_values/csv");
        sharingIntent.setData(csv); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
    }
```

I declared in my manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/comma_separated_values/csv" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And I get the exception

```
03-12 12:19:23.430: E/ActivityThread(24011): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@412fc920 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I've read this Exception occurs when there is none or just 1 option in the chooser.

[EDIT]

I changed how I attach the data to the Intent. Instead of sharingIntent.setData(csv) I used:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, csv);
```

And now the chooser works fine, but if I try to send the file via e-mail I get an error: File couldn't be shown.

[/EDIT]

Comment: The "exception" is not an exception (at least not in your app) and unrelated to the problem you have.

Comment: After your edit: Please clarify whether you want to send the file via e-mail or share it with other apps, amongst them potentially e-mail apps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct MIME type would be `text/csv`. If that doesn't work, you can use `text/plain` which will allow the user to potentially choose from a *lot* of apps, including Evernote etc.

**Update** After the update, it seems that you don't want to "share" the file with arbitrary other apps but only send it by e-mail? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to be able to share the file in every possible way, I just used e-mail to check if it worked with any of the choices. The error I placed in the edit was because I created the file using MODE_PRIVATE, if I use WORLD_READABLE and text/csv it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @ClassStacker: Neither of your suggestions work for me. Tried with `text/plain` and `text/csv`. With `*/*` it works, though...

Comment: @ClassStacker: Actually what worked for me is `text/comma-separated-values`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Actually, `text/comma-separated-values` is an official MIME type just as `text/csv` but I was so far unaware of any piece of software accepting only the somewhat lengthy variant. Which app registers to accept only `text/comma-separated-values` but not `text/csv`?

Comment: @ClassStacker: Actually, it's the OS itself. The long form is what I got from the  `getmimefromextension()` method. And my app opens csv files through its manifest only declaring an `intent-filter` with the long form. The short form fails.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Which Android OS versions did you try?

Comment: @ClassStacker JB 4.1.2. BTW, just in case I now added `text/csv` together with `text/comma-separated-values`. Who knows...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the following works in Goo:

```
intent.setType("text/*");
```

Comment: Using `text/*` for this case is in many cases undesirable. I guess you don't have many apps installed on your test system. Otherwise you would have noticed that the choice of apps handling this (when in fact they don't) is getting a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```